# Is there a simple way to look up, sum and subtract values from different entries?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, lookup

Good day everyone,

I hope you're all doing great. I want to say that I am a novice in terms of excel and sheets formulas.

I have a similar table to this in google sheets. I am focusing on 3 things, the duration of the entire shift, the break duration and the lunch duration. The break and lunch duration need to be converted to minutes or use the duration in seconds column.

[image]

I need to sum both break and lunch times per agent and subtract that total by the duration of the whole shift.

I have been throwing myself at this for longer than I would like to accept. I've been looking for formulas that could help but I haven't really found much. I got to create a helper column joining both the name and the codes together to determine which code is from which agent, but that's as far as I got.

[image]

I've also tried some INDEX(MATCH, MATCH) but nothing really comes as expected. Also tried using ARRAYFORMULA but I don't know if that'll help. Any assistance with this would be much appreciated as I really want to get to the bottom of this. I feel as though this is difficult for a novice or I am just complicating things with such a simple solution being available.

Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Are you using a new sheet for every day or each user? What is the first row in each entry?

Answer (score 0):

Firstof all, complete the names in each row with, in G1

```
={"name";ArrayFormula(lookup(row(A2:A),row(A2:A)/if(A2:A<>"",1,0),A2:A))}
```

then work with pivot table.